# Dynamically adding and persisting TextBoxes to a user control

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

Working with C# .NET 4.0 and Umbraco

I have a user control on which there is a button allowing user to dynamically add additional text boxes to the form. I've tried a myriad of methods but have been unable to persist any data entered into the dynamic text boxes between page loads.

Here's the UI:

```
<div id="new-item">
<h3>Add new menu item</h3>
<div><label for="ItemTitle">Title</label><asp:TextBox ID="ItemTitle" runat="server" CssClass="title"></asp:TextBox></div>
<div><label for="ItemDescription">Text</label><textarea id="ItemDescription" runat="server" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea></div>
<div><label for="ItemPrice">Price</label><asp:TextBox ID="ItemPrice" runat="server" CssClass="price"></asp:TextBox></div>
<div class="new-item-options">
    <p><strong>Menu item options (optional) </strong><asp:Button ID="AddMenuItemOption" runat="server" Text="Add Option" OnClick="AddOption" /></p>
    <asp:Panel ID="MenuItemOptionsPanel" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="ItemOptionCount" runat="server" />
</div>
<div><asp:Button ID="AddItemButton" runat="server" Text="Save" /></div>
<asp:HiddenField ID="ItemID" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="ItemOrder" runat="server" />
```

And in the AddOption button click event:

```
protected void AddOption(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dynamicControlCount = Convert.ToInt32(ItemOptionCount.Value) + 1;

    for (var option = 0; option < dynamicControlCount; option++)
    {
        MenuItemOptionsPanel.Controls.Add(new Literal { ID = "OptionTextLiteral" + option, Text = "<label>Option Text</label>" });
        MenuItemOptionsPanel.Controls.Add(new TextBox { ID = "OptionTextBox" + option });
        MenuItemOptionsPanel.Controls.Add(new Literal { ID = "OptionPriceLiteral" + option, Text = "<label>Option Price</label>" });
        MenuItemOptionsPanel.Controls.Add(new TextBox { ID = "OptionPriceBox" + option });
    }

    ItemOptionCount.Value = dynamicControlCount.ToString();
}
```

I know I need to create these dynamic controls in the Page_Load or OnInit methods but the problem is when the page loads for the first time, I don't want any dynamic controls create, only once the user clicks the button each time I'm like additional control added and those that already exist to have any data in them persisted.

Any ideas? I don't think I'm too far off hopefully :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you test the confition (perhaps IsPostback) in page_load, then if you need to generate the controls, do it?

Comment: Yep the generation of the controls works fine however if I place this in the Page_Load, any values entered in the existing form are lost on post back?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have to look at this (series of) [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131055/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081402-1.aspx). It explains in details how to work with dynamically created controls, especially about how to persist ViewState.

Otherwise, I would suggest you to go the AJAX way (create controls using JavaScript, post the data back to server using AJAX for the server to process). In this case, you do not have to worry about PostBack and ViewState, and it makes the user experience better too!

Comment: Thanks I've read that article however it's more around creating the controls dynamically which I have no problem with. My issue is more around persisting the values of these dynamic controls between post backs

Comment: have you read the other 2 articles, quoted at the beginning of the article? that 2 articles discuss about postback and viewstate...